# Регулярное выражение для замены содержимого ссылки

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Можно ли сделать регулярное выражение в js или noterpad++ чтобы оно нашло все ссылки :

```
<a href="нужно изменить">
```

и поменять значение ссылки на *www.example.com*, например?

Они все разные и относительные и прямые , какой **паттерн** здесь может сработать?

Comment: `/<a href="([^"]+)"\/>/gix` не подойдёт?

Comment: пробую тестировать здесь https://regex101.com/, не захватывает:  <a href="../calculator.htm"

Comment: могу дать эксель пример для этого

Comment: @Eikhner буду Вам благодарен. скиньте ссылку на пример

Comment: условия замены напишите - что искать в строке и на что менять , какие варианты написания <a href="нужно изменить"> могут быть. 
или только <a href="нужно изменить"> заменить на <a href=" www.example.com">.
фаил по одному изменять будете или в какои то папке с каким то расширением все нужно просматривать ?

Comment: Не захватывает потому что в регулярном выражении ожидается слэш и закрывающая скобка. Для указанного Вами примера: `/<a href="([^"]+)"/gix`. Имейте ввиду, что это выражение не сработает, если между открывающим тегом и атрибутом `href` будут находиться какие-либо другие теги.

Answer (score 1):

В Notepad++ можно воспользоваться выражением вроде

```
(<a\s+href=")[^"]*(">)
```

Заменить нужно `${1}моя_ссылка$2`. Первая ссылка обёрнута в фигурные скобки на случай, если `моя_ссылка` начинается с цифры. Можно использовать обратные ссылки в POSIX-стиле без фигурных скобок, `\1моя_ссылка\2`.

**Подробности**

- `(<a\s+href=")` - Группа 1:

  - `<a` - подстрока `<a`
  - `\s+` - 1 и более пробельных символов
  - `href="` - подстрока `href="`
- `[^"]*` - 0 и более символов, отличных от кавычек
- `(">)` - Группа 2: кавычка и закрывающая скобка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В JavaScript надёжнее всего найти все ссылки и задать значение атрибута `href` с помощью DOM:

```js
var txt = '<a href="some value">Text</a>';
var doc = document.createElement("div");
doc.innerHTML = txt;
var a_nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i=0; i < a_nodes.length; i++) {
  a_nodes[i].href="Моя ссылка";
}
console.log(doc.innerHTML);
```

Но если вы уверены в том, что ссылки имеют один и тот же формат (особенно в тех случаях, когда HTML создаётся "вручную"), можно обойтись и регулярным выражением:

```js
var txt = '<a href="some value">Text</a>';
var n_val = "моя ссылка$";
console.log(txt.replace(/(<a\s+href=")[^"]*(">)/g, "$1" + n_val.replace(/\$/g, '$$$$') + "$2"));
```

`n_val.replace(/\$/g, '$$$$')` необходимо, если в шаблоне замены присутствуют символы `$`.